# How to add element to List<T> and get the index back?

Tags: c#

Is there a function that would allow you to add an element to a `List<T>` and get the index as `int` back? `List<T>.Add()` is a `void` and does not return a value.

`List.Count-1` is a solution when your are not working with threads. My list is a static member and can be accessed with multiple thread at a time and using the count-1 value is totally thread unsafe and could easily lead to wrong results.

The index will be used for specific treatment to each element.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is, is `List.Add` thread safe?

Comment: Should you be using one of the concurrent collections instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

List's methods are not thread safe alone; if you just call `List.Add` repeatedly from several threads you could very well run into problems.  You need to use some sort of synchronization technique if you're going to use a `List` in the first place, so you might as well include a call to `List.Count` inside of that critical section.

Your other option would be to use a collection that is designed to be used by multiple threads, such as those in `System.Collections.Concurrent`.

Comment: +1 - But just a note that `System.Collections.Concurrent` is only available for .NET 4.0

Comment: @keyboardP Yep, which is why I listed it as just one alternative.

Comment: Well, upgrading to .Net 4.0 is not an easy one. But the solution is worth acceptance

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou If you don't want to use C# 4.0 then just `lock` all access to the list.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a thread safe index you need locking since people could have deleted an item/changed the list even if you have the index.

That said, you could try list.IndexOf(value) which returns the index of value (assuming all elements are unique)

Answer (score -2):

I believe that the list has a indexOf() method, so you can call it after adding the element to the list like this:

```
list.add(element);
int index = list.indexOf(element);
```

Comment: Not to mention the big O of indexOf() is O(N).

Comment: when your element is a collection, it is not really wise to use such method (regarding the size of the collection), specially if using threads